# using a shared_ptr object in constructor works but not in destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I have a class where the construction is like:

```
class CLSS
{
public:
    CLSS(const std::shared_ptr<someType>& pobj) 
    {
    std::shared_ptr<someType> obj = pobj;
    obj->somefunc("DDDD")
    }
    ~CLSS()
    {
    }
};
```

which works with now problem. However when I put the same function of         `obj->info("DDDD")` in the diconstructor, it returns error, that is:

```
    ...
    ~CLSS()
    {
      obj->info("DDDD")
    }
    ....
```

---------------edit

I tried

```
class CLSS
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<someType> obj;

    CLSS(const std::shared_ptr<someType>& pobj) 
    {
    obj = pobj;
    obj->somefunc("DDDD")
    }
    ~CLSS()
    {
    }
};
```

but still does not compile, the errors are not very readble.

Comment: where do you decalre the shared pointer ?

Comment: @AnisBelaid doesnt '    std::shared_ptr<someType> obj = pobj;
' already decleare it?

Comment: What error message? Reading and thinking to understand it would be helpful.

Comment: you are mising ;

Comment: Even if the errors are not very readable to you, they may be more comprehensible to the people trying to answer your question. Please edit your question to include their actual text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` is a local variable in the constructor. It is destroyed when the constructor ends.
You need to declare it as a member of your class.

Comment: I tried this declaration 'std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> log;' out of the constructor but it still did not fix it.

Comment: I edited the question with what I wrote